Are my CSS animations interfering with my links?
I have four images revolving around a central point, like a Ferris wheel. Each image is a link to a video; when the user hovers over them, they should decrease opacity and allow the user to click the link to that video. Here is an example of one such image. When I open the file in any browser, that image does not change on hover, nor does it appear linked to anything.


a img.animated {
  position: absolute;
  animation: example 10s linear infinite;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

a:hover img.animated {
  opacity: 80%;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    transform: translate(65%, -280%);
  }
  8.2% {
    transform: translate(77%, -340%);
  }
  16.5% {
    transform: translate(112%, -383%);
  }
  25% {
    transform: translate(160%, -400%);
  }
  33.2% {
    transform: translate(208%, -383%);
  }
  41.5% {
    transform: translate(238%, -340%);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translate(250%, -280%);
  }
  58.2% {
    transform: translate(238%, -220%);
  }
  66.5% {
    transform: translate(208%, -167%);
  }
  75% {
    transform: translate(160%, -150%);
  }
  88.2% {
    transform: translate(112%, -167%);
  }
  96.5% {
    transform: translate(77%, -220%);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(65%, -280%);
  }
}
<a href="https://www.youtube.com/example" target="_blank"><img class="animated" src="https://picsum.photos/id/1/200/300" alt="onevideo" /></a>



Each image has absolute position because they're placed in front of a larger image (this is also why the transform values are so extreme). I'm sure there are better ways to do something like this, but I'm largely self-taught and this is just a pet project, so I'm more concerned about the faulty links than the janky animation.

I suggest replacing the source of the img with an absolute URL; Stack Overflow obviously does not have a file named "example.jpg" in an "images" folder.

@HereticMonkey I replaced the image, and then realized the image is animated outside the viewport.

What are the transform values based on? Something like 400% of a dimension of the image you have given is quite large - why is the movement of the image dependant on its own dimensions?
